# regex validation - grails constraints

Tags: grails, constraints, grails-orm, grails-constraints

I'm pretty new on grails, I'm having a problem in matches validation using regex. What I wanted to happen is my field can accept a combination of alphanumeric and specific special characters like period (.), comma (,) and dash (-), it may accept numbers (099) or letters only (alpha) , but it won't accept input that only has special characters (".-,"). Is it possible to filter this kind of input using regex?
please help. Thank you for sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z,.-]*?[0-9a-zA-Z]+?[0-9a-zA-Z,.-]*$

meaning:
  /
  ^          beginning of the string
  [...]*?    0 or more characters from this class (lazy matching)
  [...]+?    1 or more characters from this class (lazy matching)
  [...]*     0 or more characters from this class
  $          end of the string
  /
```

Comment: Good, but since this is for Grails (which is a Java Pattern), you can't use the trailing case-insensitive match.  You should either replace it with explicit case matching (`a-zA-Z`), or use the inline flag at the beginning, `(?i)`.

Comment: Edited. Haven't worked with Java for years. Was sure RegExes were created "/stuff/flags" style.

Comment: Wow! this one really works! it's like magic! thanks for sharing and for the explanation, I understand it now, thanks to all of you!

Answer (score 1):

I think you could match that with a regular expression like this:

```
".*[0-9a-zA-Z.,-]+.*"
```

That means:

"."     *Begin with any character*

"*" *Have zero or more of these characters*

"[0-9a-zA-Z.,-]"    *Have characters in the range 0-9, a-z, etc, or . or , or -*

"+"    *Have one or more of this kind of character (so it's mandatory to have one in this set)*

"."     *End with any character*

"*"    *Have zero or more of these characters*

This is working ok for me, hope it helps!

Comment: Not exactly what I needed because it also accepts other characters other than ".,-" when you input it with alpha numeric characters, but this one also helps me to understand more about regex,Thanks for sharing chm052!